# What's the difference betwen !$scope.variableName and $scope.variableName In AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello Fellow Programmers, I'm a newbie, i see something like this and i'm thrown into deep thoughts, please explain to me the difference between the two items in AngularJs

```
$scope.variableName
```

and

```
!$scope.variableName
```

Thanks a lot, I Really Appreciate.

Comment: $scope.variableName is typical Angularjs variable deceleration and  !$scope.variableName is a Logical Not operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on the type of value you are have in `$scope.variableName`

if `$scope.variableName` is `true` then `!$scope.variableName` evaluates `false`

if `$scope.variableName` is having `null` or empty string then it evaluates to false and `!$scope.variableName` evaluates `true`

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.variableName
```

is `truthy`, it will return true when something isn't undefined, null, false or empty

```
!$scope.variableName
```

is `falsy`, it will return true if something is undefined, null, false or empty

More info about truthy values [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Answer (score 0):

'!' means 'not', using as and logical operator in programming...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators